# Container not showing, but contents are

Tags: html, smarty, prestashop-1.7

As stated in the title, I have a div with a class `.container` and, for some reason, the div is not being displayed but the contents of the div are being displayed. The height of the `.container` is also 0

This is the HTML:

```
{block name='header_logo'}
<div class="header-logo">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 hidden-sm-down" id="_desktop_logo">
                <a href="{$urls.base_url}">
                    <img class="logo img-responsive" src="{$shop.logo}" alt="{$shop.name}">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{/block}
```

and this is the inspector output:

```
<div class="header-logo">
    <div class="col-md-2 hidden-sm-down" id="_desktop_logo">
        <a href="...">
            <img class="logo img-responsive" src="..." alt="some text">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you look at the inspector output, you will see that the `.container` and the `.row` div's are not begin created. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Not sure if it's necessary, but I'm basing my theme of the prestashop classic theme.

Comment: did you included bootstrap css file correctly?

Comment: Do you know where I can check that. I only recently started learning prestashop themes. Thanks for the help

Comment: right click on your page, choose view source. and check there is bootstrap.css or bootstrap.min.css................ OR, when you select container div using inspector, is it showing any styles on bottom right corner as from bootstrap.css?

Comment: I don't see any references to bootstrap.css. How can I fix that.

Comment: Add this line to your html, between <head> and </head>,    

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: is it okay now? working? @Mr.J 01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it because you have the height as 0 ? Idk, im still new to this ...

Comment: The height is set to auto so it should automatically expand along with its contents, but its not.

Comment: well to start off, did you link it to the bootstrap css ?

Answer (score 0):

Verify you included bootstrap correctly, Add this line to your `html`, between `<head>` and `</head>`,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: change the bootstrap version to your preffered version